# In Oracle, PARALLEL is extensively used. What are the differences among PARALLEL, PARALLEL(8), PARALLEL(a,8)?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, parallel-processing, query-optimization

In Oracle, PARALLEL is extensively used. What are the differences in the hints PARALLEL, PARALLEL(8) and PARALLEL(a,8). How to choose the best hint for query?

```
SELECT /*+ PARALLEL */  * FROM BIG_TABLE_A a, BIG_TABLE_B b WHERE a.KEY=b.KEY;
SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(8) */ * FROM BIG_TABLE_A a, BIG_TABLE_B b WHERE a.KEY=b.KEY;
SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(a,8) PARALLEL(b,8) */ * FROM BIG_TABLE_A a, BIG_TABLE_B b WHERE a.KEY=b.KEY;
```

Comment: This is all documented in the manual: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements006.htm#BABHFDDH

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ref : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements006.htm#BABHFDDH

For a statement-level PARALLEL hint:

**PARALLEL:** The statement always is run parallel, and the database computes the degree of parallelism, which can be 2 or greater.

**PARALLEL (DEFAULT):** The optimizer calculates a degree of parallelism equal to the number of CPUs available on all participating instances times the value of the PARALLEL_THREADS_PER_CPU initialization parameter.

**PARALLEL (AUTO):** The database computes the degree of parallelism, which can be 1 or greater. If the computed degree of parallelism is 1, then the statement runs serially.

**PARALLEL (MANUAL):** The optimizer is forced to use the parallel settings of the objects in the statement.

**PARALLEL (integer):** The optimizer uses the degree of parallelism specified by integer.